# I want to develop an music player app for android with multitasking so dat i can use differtent apps without closing music player......help out plzz

Tags: android, multitasking, background-music

I want to develop an music player app for android with multitasking so dat i can use differtent apps without closing music player......help out plzz..

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: "Can u send me the codez?" :)

Answer (score 9):

To have it to continue to play music in the background, you will need two components to your app.  An Activity component that will display a UI to control the music player, and a Service component which is playing the music.  The Activity component controls the Service component.

See here for more details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html